# Can't connect to vpn with Network-manager

Tags: kali-linux, openvpn, networkmanager, vpn

I just installed a clean install of Kali Linux and i'm trying to use Openvpn through Network-manager but every time I press the connect button it instantly flicks back to off. (I'm using the .ovpn files I downloaded from nordvpn https://nordvpn.com/api/files/zip), (Connecting using the command line works fine),(I have followed all of the instructions at https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/openvpn/)

[image: This button keeps instantly sliding back off]

```
    Jan 28 18:11:03 kali gnome-shell[1086]: Invalid VPN service type (cannot find authentication binary)
    Jan 28 18:11:03 kali gnome-shell[1086]: Invalid VPN service type (cannot find authentication binary)
```

**Answer:**
choose 'store password for all users' in password field.
**Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1725062**

Comment: Have you followed the instructions at https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/openvpn/ ?

Comment: yes and it works when I connect through the command line but when I press the connect button in the network-manager it instantly flicks back @roaima

Comment: What error messages do you get from `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` or `journalctl -u NetworkManager.service` while trying to connect?

Comment: @roaima I added the error messages in the question

Comment: And these contain the reason why it's failing: `Invalid VPN service type (cannot find authentication binary)`.

Comment: @roaima I found the solution, thanks for the help =)

Comment: Great. Remember you can offer your own answer to your question, so others can benefit from your knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

When I updated my Kali Persistent USB, it broke my VPN, giving me the same error you experienced. After some research, I was able to fix it by updating my gnome with an

```
apt-get install gnome-shell
```

command.